# adding a variable into flash playback embeded video code

Tags: php, javascript, html, flash

It actually works fine with Chrome and Safari, however ie8 and firefox do not recognize the `$video` variable. Is there a different syntax that they might be more likely to work with these browsers.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            swfobject.registerObject("myFlashContent", "9.0.0");

    </script>
 </head>
   <?php $video="monday.mp4"; ?>
<body>
   <div>
<object width="600" height="409">
<param name="movie"value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf">              
</param>
<param name="flashvars" value="src=http%3A%2F%2F81.107.65.42%2Fmonday.mp4"></param>
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess"  
              value="always"></param> 
  <embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf"    
              type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always"
              allowfullscreen="true"    
              width="600" height="409" flashvars="src=http%3A%2F%2Fmydomain%2F"
              <?php $video; ?></embed></object>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

since it looks hard coded why not try html5 video tag?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="monday.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: html5 is not accessable to all browser versions or computers without relativity new adobe flash plugins